# Do we need both [tag:solenoid] and [tag:solenoid-valve]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Right now, we have the tag [solenoid](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solenoid), which has 48 questions, and the tag [solenoid-valve](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solenoid-valve), which has 2 questions.

Do we really need both tags?

I contend that we do not: I see only a few questions remotely related to solenoid valves (even accounting for those tagged with solenoid).  Also, someone looking for solenoid valve information would probably look under solenoid as well.

I realize I'm not a high-rep or very active member here, so my opinion may not mean much.  Thus, I want to know what the rest of the community here thinks about this.

Comment: Wait, that's discrimination against the valve minorities!

Comment: @AnindoGhosh In today's day and age...  I really don't know if that's sarcastic, or for real. :)

Comment: I'm from the earlier generation. More easily amused, less politically correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any particular policy based on whether a tag is useful or not based on the number of questions alone. In fact browsing the tags by popularity there appears to currently be several hundred that are only used by one or two questions. They automatically get cleaned up after a while if they aren't used by any questions.

While they are reasonably similar the two questions tagged [solenoid-valve](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solenoid-valve) do have aspects particular to valves so personally I think it's reasonable that it remains. The fact it only has two questions at the moment doesn't mean that in the future that it won't contain many more and become a good way to narrow down questions specific to valves.

Personally I think for tags the better measure of quality is whether they are likely to be of any benefit in the longer term.